# Odd Query Error in Mariadb

Tags: mariadb-10.5

This query works without an error (I am running this query in HeidiSQL and 10.5.22-MariaDB)

```
SELECT concat(d.fname, ' ', d.Lname) AS Name, 
       d.EMail, 
       d1.Number 
FROM orders d
LEFT OUTER JOIN phones d1 ON d.EMail = d1.Number
where (d.EMail <> '')
HAVING d1.Number IS NULL;
```

If I enclose it in (), I get an error (was getting an error when I used it
as a subquery which is why I tried this.

```
(
SELECT concat(d.fname, ' ', d.Lname) AS Name, 
       d.EMail, 
       d1.Number 
FROM orders d
LEFT OUTER JOIN phones d1 ON d.EMail = d1.Number
where (d.EMail <> '')
HAVING d1.Number IS NULL;
)
```

The error is

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: You have forgot the semicolon before the latest  `)` at this line `HAVING d1.Number IS NULL;`. Apart from the error can you show us what are you trying to achieve ? To me it doesn't make any sense using  HAVING without a group by . [Working example of your query](https://dbfiddle.uk/FNQSIGVe)

Answer (score 0):

This answer did help me in that i removed the semicolon within the subquery and it worked. Thanks.

i believe there is a semicolon before the last parantheses unless i am really missing something. as i said the query works with the external parantheses but doesn't when i enclose it in parantheses which is what i do not understand. Having .. null just gives me the records which do not match.